# is it possible making openssl skipping the country/common name prompts?

Tags: openssl

Is there a way to make openssl skiping the prompts such as

```
Country Name (2 letter code) [US]:
Organization Name (eg, company) [My Company Name LTD.]:
Common Name (eg, YOUR name) [something]:
```

While creating certificates with

```
openssl req -config openssl.cnf -new -x509 ...
```

given the fact those parameters are provided in the `openssl.cnf` file

e.g.

```
countryName         = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default     = US
countryName_min     = 2
countryName_max     = 2
0.organizationName      = Organization Name (eg, company)
0.organizationName_default  = My Company Name LTD.
commonName          = Common Name (eg, YOUR name)
commonName_max      = 64
commonName_default      = ${ENV::CN}
```

Comment: You can pass those things as parameters on the command line.  I don't recall the syntax.

Comment: thanks, that works!
`-subj '/C=US/ST=Oregon/L=Portland/CN=www.madboa.com'` is the way to go

Answer (score 160, accepted):

thanks to [@indiv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19719/indiv)

according to this [guide](http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/) `-subj` is the way to go, e.g.

```
-subj '/CN=www.mydom.com/O=My Company Name LTD./C=US'
```

Comment: indeed, no config file needed this way

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is shown last … thanks

Comment: doesn't work in inside bash script in cygwin bash.

Comment: @Maik That is because cygwin assumes `/CN...` is a filename and attempts to translate it into a windows file path. You can prevent this with `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV`, e.g. `env MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 openssl ...` (or an `export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1` in front).

Answer (score 48):

Another solution consists of using the **`prompt = no`** directive in your config file.
See [OpenSSL: Configuration file format](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-req.html#CONFIGURATION-FILE-FORMAT)

#### `prompt`

> if set to the value `no` this disables prompting of certificate fields and just takes values from the config file directly. It also changes the expected format of the `distinguished_name` and `attributes` sections.
>
> There are two separate formats for the `distinguished name` and `attribute` sections.
>
> **If the prompt option is set to `no` then these sections just consist of field names and values**: for example,
>
> ```
> CN = My Name
> OU = My Organization
> emailAddress = someone@somewhere.org
> ```
>
> This allows external programs (e.g. GUI based) to generate a template file with all the field names and values and just pass it to `req`.
>
> Alternatively if the prompt option is absent or not set to no then the file contains field prompting information. It consists of lines of the form:
>
> ```
> fieldName="prompt"
> fieldName_default="default field value"
> fieldName_min= 2
> fieldName_max= 4
> ```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. If there is a config file already, there is no point is providing the /CN /O /C options is the command again.

Comment: @AdityaVikasDevarapalli 8 years after having written this answer, I agree. But I am biased.

Answer (score 20):

Generate a config file and in the [req] section you can put prompt = no.

For example:

```
[req]
prompt = no
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = v3_req

[req_distinguished_name]
C = US
ST = California
L = Los Angeles
O = Our Company Llc
#OU = Org Unit Name
CN = Our Company Llc
#emailAddress = info@example.com

[v3_req]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = example.com
DNS.2 = www.example.com
```

Then just execute e.g.

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -config THATFILE.conf -key example.com.key -out example.com.csr
```

Answer (score 10):

**A mixed approach is not supported**

It may be intuitive to think that a mixed approach is possible, where you may think of putting some static fields in openssl.cnf and specify some (CN) via `-subj` option. However, that does not work.

I tested a scenario where I

- put C, ST, L, O and OU in the openssl.cnf section
  `req_distinguished_name` and
- ran `openssl req` with
  `-subj=/CN=www.mydom.com`.

openssl complained that mandatory Country Name field is missing and the generated certificate just had CN in the subject line. Seems like `-subj` option completely overrides the subject line and does not allow updating a single field.

This makes all following three approaches of supplying subject fields exclusive to each other:

- Prompts
- config file
- `-subj` option

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. This really should be flagged as a bug. When I run it, `-subj` is ignored even if specified after `-config`.

Answer (score 7):

The `-batch` optional parameter causes the `openssl req` command to not prompt for any of the information fields. I use it this way without an explicit config file for automation of self-signed certs.

It is listed in the help:

```
openssl help req
...
...
-batch              Do not ask anything during request generation
```

Comment: I guess it is not really without a config file: if not specified, it is taken from a default location and fails if it wasn't installed there.

Comment: Good clarification, I updated my answer to say "explicit config file" in light of that.