# Automate SSL creation in Fabric (Python)

Tags: python, ssl, python-2.7, openssl, fabric

I'm using Fabric to automate SSL creation, but when I run something like

```
local('openssl genrsa  -out /etc/ssl/'+hostname+'/'+hostname+'.key 2048')
```

it prompts me for country, state, an email address, etc. Is there anything I can do (possibly with an openssl.cnf?) to prevent the need for user input with those prompts, or do people usually just hack it using something like pexpect?

**Update:**

If I put `prompt=no` in my openssl.cnf, `cd` to `/ssdhome/development/server`, then run:

```
sudo openssl req -new -key './server.key' -out './server.csr' -config='./openssl.cnf'
```

openssl prints out `help` information instead of running the above command. Where have I gone wrong?

**Update 2**: -config should not have an '=' sign, but a space. Solved. Also linked to this copy of my openssl.cnf to get it working:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSSL

Comment: I think this is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075274/is-it-possible-making-openssl-skipping-the-country-common-name-prompts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How to answer to prompts automatically with python fabric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479078)

```
from ilogue.fexpect import expect, expecting, run

def sample():

    private_key = "password"
    hostname = "ubuntu"
    output_dir = '/etc/ssl/' + hostname
    prompts = []
    prompts += expect('Enter pass phrase for private.key:',private_key)
    prompts += expect('Verifying - Enter pass phrase for private.key:private_key',private_key)
    prompts += expect('Enter pass phrase for %s/server.key:' % output_dir, private_key)
    prompts += expect('Country Name \(2 letter code\) \[AU\]:','AU')
    prompts += expect('State or Province Name \(full name\) \[Some-State\]:','State')
    prompts += expect('Locality Name \(eg, city\) \[\]:','City')
    prompts += expect('Organization Name \(eg, company\) \[Internet Widgits Pty Ltd\]:','Company')
    prompts += expect('Organizational Unit Name \(eg, section\) \[\]:','Section')
    prompts += expect('Common Name \(e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name\) \[\]:','FQDN')
    prompts += expect('Email Address \[\]:','email@foo.com')
    prompts += expect('A challenge password \[\]:','challenge_password')
    prompts += expect('An optional company name \[\]:','optional_company')

    with expecting(prompts):
        run('openssl genrsa -des3 -out %s/server.key 2048' % output_dir)
        run('openssl req -new -key %s/server.key -out %s/server.csr' % (output_dir, output_dir))

# fab sample -H localhost
```

the regular expression is applied to expect(), you need to escape [, ], (, ) ...

Answer (score 1):

Used https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSSL to get `prompt=no` to stop throwing errors and `-config ./openssl.cnf` to automate the prompts thanks to user alecxe.